# Connect multiple clients to tcp server. Python

Tags: python, multithreading, tcp, tcpclient

I have an assignment but I have some queries.

I already have my TCP server on AWS with threads so I can handle multiple connections.

But I need to connect at least 25 clients, and get some files at the same time (after all 25 clients are connected and I must select which file to download between 2 files).

So I guess I have to use threads on my client script too, but I am not sure how to coordinate it and if my server can have multiple TCP connections from the same IP. I am not sure how to approach this.

I already have a client but it is just a single connection.

I need some ideas to approach the problem, I was thin

Comment: *"... but I am not sure how to coordinate it and if my server can have multiple TCP connections from the same IP."* - it is unclear what you want to coordinate. And if your server can handle multiple connections from the same IP depends on the server. Usually they do unless they have specifically implemented restrictions to not allow this.

Comment: I want to coordinate the 25 connections to download at the same time, but I guess i can do that from the server side. I will create 25 clients with threads and try!